# GCP Folders/Projects/VPC creation automation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP and exploring options to automate Projects and VPC creation. I have found that Cloud foundation tool kit provides an option to automate these though Terraform and Deployment manager templates. So, I have modified those Terraform templates according to my requirement and tested those. It's working fine. But now I need to know the best practices where to store these code repo's and create a pipeline to automate projects and VPC creation. Scenario would be internal application team would submit a form with their requirement, at that time these pipeline should be triggered and Projects, VPC should be created. At the same time, If i make any modifications to those code repo's all existing projects should also be updated. For AWS, there is a solution for this called Cloud formation stack sets. So is there anything similar to that in GCP? Also, to use Deployment manager templates what's the best practice and how we can create a pipeline for above said scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Gopal

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Serverfault.

I'm also interested by automated deployment and workflow processes. Few time ago I read an interesting [blog](https://www.toptal.com/devops/better-google-cloud-continuous-deployment) regarding continuous deployment (CD) which I hope that will give you some inspiration to build up your deployment pipeline.

That being said, here is the [Google Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices) for Deployment Manager usage.
There is also the [developper hub](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd) which include templates and ideas that you can base on.